# Microsoft Point of Service - PosPrinter.FromIdAsync Returns "A device attached to the system is not functioning"

Tags: c#, uwp, epson, pos, posprinter

I'm trying to use MS PosPrinter into UWP app, my Epson Tm-T20II printer is installed and can print using Epson oPos setup utility.

Even I installed the full windows driver and it works.

My problem comes when I run this:

```
DevicePicker devicePicker = new DevicePicker();
devicePicker.Filter.SupportedDeviceSelectors.Add(PosPrinter.GetDeviceSelector());

// Anchor the picker on the Find button.
GeneralTransform ge = FindButton.TransformToVisual(Window.Current.Content as UIElement);
Rect rect = ge.TransformBounds(new Rect(0, 0, FindButton.ActualWidth, FindButton.ActualHeight));

DeviceInformation deviceInfo = await devicePicker.PickSingleDeviceAsync(rect);
rootPage.deviceInfo = deviceInfo;
PosPrinter printer = null;
if (deviceInfo != null)
{
    printer = await PosPrinter.FromIdAsync(deviceInfo.Id);
}
```

`await PosPrinter.FromIdAsync(deviceInfo.Id)` always return:

```
System.Exception: 'A device attached to the system is not functioning. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007001F)'
```

This is my test from oPos setup.

[image]

Some Idea about this problem?

Comment: https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/blob/5c5b53b6c0df64a3027405ecf9e5c19a18ca8605/Samples/PosPrinter/cs/Package.appxmanifest#L53

Comment: @HansPassant Are you talking about 
        ``<DeviceCapability Name="pointOfService" />`` Is already checked, I'm totally lost with this. Tks for help

Comment: @NicoZhu-MSFT No the problem persists even with ``pointOfService`` capability active . Printer is already recognized by ``DevicePicker ``, but the problem is when try to get the printer by id  using  ``PosPrinter.FromIdAsync()``.

Comment: Correctly we have no such device for testing, I will escalate this case to related team. If I get some info, I will update below.

Comment: @NicoZhu-MSFT Tks. Just a Question this printer is a USB printer, does it matter?

Comment: it doesn't matter. it is connection well,  if you could find the device in device management list  with out yellow warning.

Comment: @NicoZhu-MSFT It is at **Inherited OPOS devices** on **Devices manager** and no Yellow warning. just as enabled device.

Comment: @NicoZhu-MSFT Hi Nico, any news about it ?

Comment: @NicoZhu-MSFT Almost 2 years about this issue, no news about it is this a deprecated prokject on MS ?

Comment: I just ran into this problem using an epson TM-88V.  Anyone found a solution? @NicoZhu-MSFT?

Comment: @NebulaSleuth Hi, seems like MS forget's about this project. But I found a real universal solution https://github.com/lukevp/ESC-POS-.NET This is the way I do to print. on UWP / .NET/ .Net core